# nginx configuration that could serve 1000 requests/sec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, webserver

Our production server have Ubuntu 9.x, 
Memory 8GB, HDD 250Gb use nginx as webserver. 
We currently experiencing performances problem during peak hours (1000requests/sec)
I want server can serve 1000requests/sec, can someone tell me what should i change on nginx configuration. thanks

here is nginx conf

```
#user  nobody;

worker_processes  8;

events {
    worker_connections  8024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9;
    passenger_ruby /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10/bin/ruby;
    passenger_pool_idle_time 0;
    passenger_max_pool_size 15;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    ## General options
    #ignore_invalid_headers on;
    keepalive_requests 2000;
    #recursive_error_pages on;
    #server_name_in_redirect off;
    #server_tokens off;

    ## TCP options
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    ## Timeouts
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #send_timeout 10;
    #expires 24h;

    gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  resumecompanion.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    root /var/www/resumecompanion.com/production/current/public;
    #access_log  off;
    #error_log off;
            ## Redirect from www to non-www
            if ($host = 'www.resumecompanion.com' ) {
              rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://resumecompanion.com/$1  permanent;
            }


            # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
            # concurs with nginx's one
            #
            location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
            }
        }


# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  resumecompanion.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /opt/nginx/ssl/resumecompanion.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /opt/nginx/ssl/start_resumecompanion_com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    root   /var/www/resumecompanion.com/production/current/public;

}
```

}

Comment: For 8024 worker_connections with 8 worker_processes  you also need to modify your kernel parameters: ulimit -n 64192 (8*8024). The best to set the number of processes equal to the number of cpu cores as well.

Comment: @petermolnar That can be done with worker_rlimit_nofile in Nginx as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is very hard to say without analyzing the system... You have to first find where most of the time is being spent in the requests. Its not common ngingx or apache being the casue of problem.

Considering you posted this with a ruby-on-rails tag I suppose you have a rails app behind nginx... It is much more likely being the rails app the one causing problems. The first thing I would check is the database queries. Check the logs for slow queries and try to find a way to make them faster... indexes are always a good point to start....

If you can not find anything try with tools as new relic that will find where your performance issues are...